# Ошибка. Ожидается ';'

Tags: pascal

```
var a,v,b,e:integer;
begin
    writeln('введите a,v,b,e');
    readln(a,v,b,e);
    a+b=:c:
    b*e=:f:
    writeln('ответ=', f);
    readln(f);
    writeln('ответ=', c);
    readln(c);
end.
```

Вот текст ошибки:

> Program1.pas(5,2): Встречено '+', а ожидалось ';'

Что нужно исправить?

Comment: эм, а что тут вообще должно было происходить?

Comment: @Grundy - Это неважно. Ошибка не имеет никакого отношения к тому, что должно происходить :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

минимальные исправления, что бы оно "заработало". Гарантии, что оно решает поставленную задачу - нет.

```
var a,v,b,e,c,f:integer;
begin
    writeln('введите a,v,b,e');
    readln(a,v,b,e);
    c:=a+b;
    f:=b*e;
    writeln('ответ=', f);
    writeln('ответ=', c);
end.
```

конструкция `a+b=:c:` очень похожа на смыслу на конструкцию с языка [Рапира](http://agat9.narod.ru/TECH/STAN_FIL/RAPIRA.HTM). Там бы это писалось так `a+b->c`.

Comment: а там слева на право вычисляется?

Comment: конструкция `expr -> var;` эквивалентна `var := expr;` То есть, вычисляем выражение как обычно и результат записываем в переменную.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему перепутаны местами что где вычисляется и куда присваивается.

Оператор присваивания выглядит `:=` с левой части - куда присваивать, с правой - что присвоить

таким образом данные выражения синтаксически не корректны

```
a+b=:c:
b*e=:f:
```

И из контекста должно быть так

```
c := a+b;
f := b*e;
```